# Deleting rows based on previous cells in R

Tags: r

I am trying to reshape my data by generating a dummy variable and deleting some observations. It has the following form:

```
> df
   id GP
1   1  0
2   1  3
3   1  4
4   2  0
5   2  3
6   2  0
7   3  2
8   3  2
9   4  5
10  4  0
>
```

GP refers to *games played*. Now I want to generate a dummy variable lets call it `entry` that shows when a player **first** started playing and then I want to delete observations after the player has first entered. My final dataset should look like this:

```
    > df
       id GP entry
    1   1  0  0
    2   1  3  1
    3   2  0  1
    4   2  3  1
    5   3  2  1
    6   4  5  1
    >
```

Hence, rows number 3, 6, 8 and 10 of the original dataset were deleted. I have tried generating a a dummy variable and then deleting rows:

```
df$entry <- ifelse(df$GP > 0, 1, 0)

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df <- df[! (df$entry[i] ( if (df$entry[i] == 1 & df$entry[i-1] == 1 & df&id[i] == df&id[i-1] |
                              df$entry[i] == 1 & df$entry[i-1] == 0 & df&id[i] == df&id[i-1] ))),]
}
```

Here I generated a dummy that equals to 1 whenever `GP > 0` and then I wanted to delete the observations according to the if condition in the loop. That is, delete rows in which a player
has `entry = 1` more than once and rows after `entry = 1`. However, I get the following error

```
Error: unexpected ')' in:
"  df <- df[! (df$entry[i] ( if (df$entry[i] == 1 & df$entry[i-1] == 1 & df&id[i] == df&id[i-1] |
                              df$entry[i] == 1 & df$entry[i-1] == 0 & df&id_test[i] == df&id_test[i-1] ))"
```

Deleting the parenthesis only results in further errors.  I would gladly appreciate any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(cumsum(cumsum(GP > 0)) < 2) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 2
     id    GP
  <int> <int>
1     1     0
2     1     3
3     2     0
4     2     3
5     3     2
6     4     5
```

---

Or with `slice`

```
df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   slice(seq_len(which(GP > 0)[1])) %>%
   ungroup
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), 
    GP = c(0L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 0L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! I just have a question regarding your first code. I don't quite understand your 4th line  `filter(cumsum(cumsum(GP > 0)) < 2) %>%`
 with its last condition being  that the cumulative sum has to be `<2`.

Comment: @twoRay `cumsum(GP > 0)` get the cumulative sum by incrementing where GP is greater than 1, doing the cumsum again, increments the next occurrence of GP > 0 to 2, 3, etc.   By doing `< 2`, we get the row till the first occurrence

Answer (score 3):

```
df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   filter(row_number() <= which.max(GP > 0))

# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   id [4]
     id    GP
  <int> <int>
1     1     0
2     1     3
3     2     0
4     2     3
5     3     2
6     4     5
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. When I run this code on my original dataset, then too many observations are actually deleted. Nevertheless, the code from akrun worked. But could you also explain what the 3rd line of code is actually doing? `filter(row_number() <= which.max(GP > 0))`

Answer (score 2):

For this dataset this should work. Please check it for your original dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(entry = lead(GP)) %>% 
  na.omit %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(entry = ifelse(row_number()==1, 0, 1))
```

```
     id    GP entry
  <int> <int> <dbl>
1     1     0     0
2     1     3     1
3     2     0     1
4     2     3     1
5     3     2     1
6     4     5     1
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately, it does not work for my original dataset. Too many rows are deleted after running the code.